# Polymer : upgrading from 1.2.1 to 1.2.3 broke display

Tags: html, polymer, upgrade

I've just upgraded Polymer from 1.2.1 to 1.2.3 (with several Polymer elements).

When reloading my application, the html was not filling the entire page.
When taking a look at the css, i saw that the height of the is 488.031px, without changing anything, and a 8px margin has been added to my body.

If I set a specific height to my body (like 950px) the html fill the 950px.
But without this, only half of the page is filled and displayed

Does anyone encountered the same problem, or anyone has an idea about what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it

My body was :

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical"></body>
```

But the iron-flex-layout.html wasn't included, that's why my body was not filling the entire page, maybe some modifications have been added to polymer, that's why my page was broken